# Rewrite into a Generic abstract class or interface

Tags: vb.net

I want to write the following into a generic abstract/interface so any class that inherits/extends the abstract class, has this in there:

```
<XmlRootAttribute("root")> _
Public Class myXMLCollection
    Inherits BatchFiles
    <XmlElement("data")> _
    Public Property myXMLCollection() As myXML()

End Class
```

The root attribute and element can change based on the file/class that uses the above.

Not sure where to begin with this.

The caller would do something like this:

```
Dim myXMLDontKnowWhichOne as ImyXML (or the abstract class)
Dim type as Type
If xyz = True Then
 type = GetType(myXMLclassforAnotherFile)
Else
 type = GetType(myXMLclassgenericforallotherfiles)
End If

myXMLDontKnowWhichOne = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

Option Strict is On so can't use late-binding stuff and would need this to be as generic as possible.

Asking for advice and to point me in the right direction. Wish I knew more about OO to answer this myself and all other sites seems a bit confusing in this use-case scenario

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged under C#?

Comment: Because I don't care if c# answers are also given :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have the same property `myXMLCollection` but different root name and element name for each class and also inherit BatchFiles in each case.  I'd have said use an interface but because you need to inherit from another class you'll have to use an abstract base class.

```
Public MustInherit Class myXMLCollectionBase
    Inherits BatchFiles

    Public MustOverride Property myXMLCollection() As myXML()

End Class
```

And then in each implementation do

```
<XmlRootAttribute("root1")> _
Public Class myXMLclassforAnotherFile
    Inherits myXmlCollectionBase

    <XmlElement("data1")> _
    Public Property myXMLCollection() As myXML()

End Class

<XmlRootAttribute("root2")> _
Public Class myXMLclassgenericforallotherfiles
    Inherits myXmlCollectionBase

    <XmlElement("data2")> _
    Public Property myXMLCollection() As myXML()

End Class
```

You could then do what you've done with the activator and create an instance of the type but better would be to use a factory, I'll call it XmlFactory which is not a great name.

```
Public Class XmlFactory

    Public Shared Function GetXml() As myXMLCollectionBase
         If xyz = True Then
            Return new myXMLclassforAnotherFile()
         Else
            Return new myXMLclassgenericforallotherfiles()
         End If
     End Function

End Class
```

Apologies for any syntax errors - I'm more of a C# developer!

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I tagged c# as well, as I'm bi-lingual, lol. Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. I was on the right track but missed some key points.